# Why does /etc/shadow uses user name instead of uid?

Tags: users, password, passwd, shadow

`/etc/shadow` contains the username, but not the uid. Is there a specific reason, why a `char *` field was chosen over an int?

For direct username->password check this might be quicker, but for relations to `/etc/passwd` a string-comparison on each user seems a little expensive.

I'd like to know the rationale behind this decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be multiple users with the same uid (but different name, home directory, shell, etc) in `/etc/passwd`. And that was current practice -- IIRC even today, there's a `toor` "alternate root" account on BSD.

If the `/etc/shadow` passwords were indexed by uid instead of user name, then which `/etc/passwd` entry would each of them  correspond to?

Comment: Is this actually the real reason? As I understand from here: https://askubuntu.com/a/427115/594043, two user should actually not have the same u**ID**.

Comment: well, they could've matched & duplicate *all* the fields from `/etc/passwd` in `/etc/shadow` (as it's the case in some systems), but they chose not to. Since they decided to match on a single key, using the uid would've broken setups which used multiple usernames with the same uid (which really exist, no matter if it's good idea or not).

Comment: It's generally not a great idea to have multiple usernames for the same uid, but if your system depends on `root` having `/bin/csh` as its shell, and your system administrators loathe csh, it might be helpful. Some BSD systems provide a `toor` username with uid 0 and shell `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @Mark BSD systems also don't use /etc/shadow, but an /etc/master.passwd which duplicates all the fields from /etc/passwd (name, uid, homedir, etc). Anyways, multiple users with the same uid could not work if /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow had the uid as the "common key". But they would work if *both* the user name and the uid were matched.